# Read Fortran binary file into C# without knowledge of Fortran source code?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, fortran

Part one of my question is even if this is possible? I will briefly describe my situation first.

My work has a licence for a software that performs a very specific task, however most of our time is spent exporting data from the results into excel etc to perform further analysis. I was wondering if it was possible to dump all of the data into a C# object so that I can then write my own analysis code, which would save us a lot of time.

The software we licence was written in Fortran, but we have no access to the source code. The file looks like it is written out in binary, however I do not know if it is unformatted / sequential etc (is there anyway to discern this?).

I have used some of the other answers on this site to successfully read in the data to a byte[], however this is as far as I have got. I have tried to change portions to doubles (which I assume most of the data is) but the numbers do not strike me as being meaningful (most appear too large or too small).

I have the documentation for the software and I can see that most of the internal variable names are 8 character strings, would this be saved with the data? If not I think it would be almost impossible to match all the data to its corresponding variable. I imagine most of the data will be double arrays of the same length (the number of time points), however there will also be some arrays with a longer length as some data would have been interpolated where shorter time steps were needed for convergence.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated, or even if someone tells me its just not possible so I don't waste any more time trying to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should ask the vendor for a specification of the output file format and check (with the vendor) whether that licensed software has other data export options.

Comment: You say you spend time exporting data to Excel, etc, but then you say "The file looks like it is written out in binary."  Do you mean the output file, or the Fortran executable?  If you can't read the output file, how have you been importing things into Excel?

Comment: FYI, it pays to stick around on the site for a while after asking a question, so you can respond to comments requesting clarification, etc.  Sometimes people can't answer without more information about the problem, which I believe is the case here.

Comment: We export to excel using the software's GUI, which is cumbersome and we can only export one variable at a time, hence the desire to dump all the data at once. The output file I'm trying to read is the results file saved by the software (it's finite element analysis software). And I'll keep that in mind next time adv12.

Comment: A few more questions to get an better idea: What operating system are you using, and what is the file name (or, more precisely, extension) of the data file? Thanks

Comment: I am using windows 7, the file extension is .fem (which I assume stands for finite element model). It doesn't appear to be a commonly used file extension, possibly unique to this software.

Comment: Also, the software is not commercially available, it's the in-house software of a large company we do consultancy work for.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, but that is about as far as I can help you. I have found online some indication linking the extension `.fem` to a CADRE finite element analysis software, but I couldn't find any information on the file format. It might be that the actual data is preceded with a header, which might very well throw you off.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have convinced me that this is no trivial task and that I should probably contact the vendor for more information on the file format if I want to progress this further. If I could upvote your answers I would but my rating is not yet high enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it was formatted, you should be able to read it with a text editor: The numbers are written in plain text.

So yes, it's probably unformatted.

There are different methods still. The file can have a fixed record length, or it might have a variable one.

But it seems to me that the first 4 bytes represent an integer containing the length of that record in bytes. For example, here I've written the numbers 1 to 10, and then 11 to 30 into an unformatted file, and the file looks like this:

```
40 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 40 
80 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 80
```

(I added the new line) In here, the first 4 bytes represent the number 40, followed by 10 4-byte blocks representing the numbers 1-10, followed by another 40. The next record starts with an 80, and 20 4-byte blocks containing the numbers 11 through 30, followed by another 80.

So that might be a pattern you could try to see. Read the first 4 bytes and convert them to integer, then read that many bytes and convert them to whatever you think it should be (4 byte float, 8 byte float, et cetera), and then check whether the next 4 bytes again represents the number that you read first.

But there other methods to write data in Fortran that doesn't seem to have this behaviour, for example direct access and stream. So no guarantees.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately the first int read seems far too high, it takes me right past the end of the stream.

Comment: In that case I would probably try to get my calculator out and try to calculate how many values there must be. Then at least you can make a guess by comparing the size of the file with the number of elements how many bytes there might be per value.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming that they use a proprietary format. Maybe that's not the case. What's the file ending?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm doing this correct as this is the first time Iv had to do any low level I/O but if I take the last 4 bytes as an int I get -536805376.